# was going to...but - does it have to be like that?

Tags: usage

**Example 1**

> I was going to go to the movies, but I was too tired to go.

**Example 2**

> I wasn't going to make him feel bad, but I used the wrong words.

Many online resources used the pattern "was going to...but" or "wasn't going to...but"

However, does it have to be like that?

Can we use them like below

**Example 3**

> I was going to go to the movies, and I had a good time watching movie.

**Example 4**

> I wasn't going to make him feel bad, and I didn't.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your examples are possible with a specific context, though 3 is a little odd.

"*I was/wasn't going to X*" means "*I was determined to do/not do X*". Normally, that's followed up with the opposite happening, but it could also be followed by someone following through on their intention.

So your sentences can be rewritten:

> 3. I was determined that I would go to the movies, and (I followed through on my intention and) had a good time.
> 4. I was determined not to make him feel bad, and I succeeded.

Sentence 3 is a little odd for a couple reasons: (1) going to the movies is pretty easy, so normally someone wouldn't need to be determined to do it; and (2) the result should include that you did go to the movies, not merely imply it by saying you had a good time. If there's nothing special about going to the movies, then just say you went to the movies. No need to introduce your intent first.

Sentence 4 is fine if it has the meaning that you were determined not to make him feel bad before going in, and perhaps unsure of your ability to succeed, but then you succeeded.

Comment: 3 could work in a context where unusual obstacles came up in the attempt to go to the movies - I'm picturing a sitcom situation where you can't find your wallet or keys, then your car won't start, then the bus leaves just before you get to the stop, etc.. Odd, to be sure, but context could make it work.

Comment: @minnmass Possibly better example would be "I was going to go to the movies even though I was grounded..."